# How can I send request payload data using a JSON file in GO?

Tags: json, go, post

I'm really new to coding and Golang itself.
I would like to know how can I send request Payload data using a JSON file in GO?

I mean, I have a post request and the JSON file and I would like to put it into the request body but I am coming across some errors.

The request is working when I use an alternative HTTP client.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you have written?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the nature of the HTTP request, you may be able to use an existing client package. Eg, [JSON RPC](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=json+rpc&m=package).

Here is an example if you would like to understand how to make a request using the standard library. This example also demonstrates using [context](https://pkg.go.dev/context) to set timeouts for client requests:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    var client http.Client

    reqCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Minute)
    defer cancel()
    err := deleteEntry(reqCtx, &client, 42)

    fmt.Println(err)
}

func deleteEntry(ctx context.Context, client *http.Client, entryID int) error {
    payload := &struct {
        EntryID int    `json:"entry_id"`
        Method  string `json:"method"`
    }{
        EntryID: entryID,
        Method:  "delete",
    }

    buf, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "POST", "http://localhost/example", bytes.NewReader(buf))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Note: Response body must always be closed.
    // Response body data (if any) should be consumed before closure, otherwise the
    // the client connection may not be reused.
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return fmt.Errorf("request failed with %s", resp.Status)
    }
    return nil
}
```

I'd recommend reading through the [net/http](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) documentation to gain a better understanding. In particular:

- [http.Request](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request)
- [http.Response](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response)